# How to write the Cartesian product of all elements of an uncountable set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

Let $A$ be an uncountable set with arbitrary element $a\in A$. I want to define the Cartesian product of all its elements. In other words, all the vectors belonging to

\begin{gather}
\underbrace{A\times\dots\times A}_{A}
\end{gather}

Suppose $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$. Then, I am looking for the notation that generalises the following expression to the case in which the set $A$ is uncountable:

\begin{gather}
A\times A\equiv\{(a_1,a_1),(a_1,a_2),(a_2,a_1),(a_2,a_2)\}
\end{gather}

I have thought of two possibilities, but both seem unsatisfactory:

1. To define $\prod_{a\in A}i(a)$, where $i:A\to A$ is the identity function (i.e., $i(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$);
2. To simply define $\prod_{a\in A}a$.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your example with two elements doesn't clarify it for me. Let's say $A$ has three elements. Do you want a set with all 9 possible ordered pairs, or a set will all possible 27 ordered triples? If your set were $\mathbb{N}$, do you want the set with all possible sequences of natural numbers?

Comment: If $A$ had three elements, I would want the set with all possible 27 ordered triples.

Comment: Then what you want is $\prod_{a\in A} A$, or equivalently $A^A$, the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$.

Comment: I don’t see why $\prod_{a\in A}A$ rather than $\prod_{a\in A}a$.

Comment: $\prod_{a\in A}a$ would given tuples in which the $a$th entry is an *element* of $a$, not an element of $A$. By definition, $\prod_{i\in I} S_i$ is the set of all functions $f\colon I\to \cup S_i$ such that $f(i)\in S_i$. If $A=\{ \varnothing, \{1\}\}$, then $\prod_{a\in A}A$ is $\{(\varnothing,\varnothing), (\varnothing,\{1\}), (\{1\},\varnothing),(\{1\},\{1\})$, whereas $\prod_{a\in A}a$ is $\varnothing\times \{1\}$, which is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me ask one last question regarding your comment. If $A\equiv\{a_1,a_2\}$, **is it true that $\prod_{a\in A}a\equiv a_1\times a_2\equiv (a_1,a_2)$?**

Comment: It is true that $\prod_{a\in A}a = a_1\times a_2$. It is **false** that $a_1\times a_2 = (a_1,a_2)$. After all, $a_1\times a_2 = \{ (x,y)\mid x\in a_1, y\in a_2\}$.

Comment: Thanks again! Suppose, though, that $a_1=\{a_1\}$ and $a_2=\{a_2\}$. **Would it then be true that $a_1\times a_2\equiv (a_1,a_2)$?**

Comment: First, in standard set theory, there are no sets that satisfy $x=\{x\}$. **If** you are working in a non-standard set theory where that is possible, then $a_1\times a_2 = \{ (a_1,a_2)\}$ the set whose only element is the ordered pair $(a_1,a_2)$. **Second,** depending on your definition of the ordered pair, it could be that $\{(a_1,a_2)\} = (a_1,a_2)$, but most of the time they won't be equal.  I would say you **do not** want to live in a world where $x=\{x\}$ is even possible right now, at least until you actually want to start thinking about non-standard set theories.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. Let me re-frase my last comment. Suppose that instead of setting $a_1=\{a_1\}$ and $a_2=\{a_2\}$, which is illegal in standard set theory, I just set $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be singletons. **Would it then be the case that $a_1\times a_2=(a_1,a_2)$?** *I am just trying to figure out the meaning of $\prod_{a\in A}a$ when all $a\in A$ are singletons. Any help will be much appreciated.*

Comment: Again, no. You keep playing fast and loose with "the set whose only element is $a$" and $a$. If $a_1=\{x\}$, and $a_2=\{y\}$ (singletons), then $a_1\times a_2 = \{(x,y)\}$, the set whose only element is the ordered pair $(x,y)$. It is **not** $(x,y)$, it is **not** $(a_1,a_2)$, and it is **not** $\{(a_1,a_2)\}$. If $a=\{x_a\}$ is a singleton, then $\prod_{a\in A} a = \{(x_a)\mid a\in A\}$, the set whose only element is the $A$-tuple that has $x_a$ is in the $a$th coordinate; **not** the tuple that has $a$ in the $a$th coordinate.

Comment: Thank you again. Given $A\equiv\{a_1,a_2\}$, let $i:A\to A$ be the identity function. **Is it then true that $\prod_{a\in A}i(a)\equiv i(a_1)\times i(a_2)\equiv \{(a_1,a_2)\}$?**

Comment: For the **n** th time. **NO**. All you did was add irrelevant notation. $\prod_{a\in A} i(a) =\prod_{a\in A} a =a_1\times a_2 \neq \{(a_1,a_2)\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. There certainly is something I’m not grasping, but I won’t bother you anymore. I sincerely appreciate your help —it’s time to do some more research on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not exactly sure *what* you want. From your *text* I suppose you want
$$ \prod_{a\in A} a$$
from your formulae I get you want
$$ \prod_{A}A = A^A $$
The latter can be understood as all functions from $A$ to $A$. The first one can be understood as all maps $f$ from $A$ to $\bigcup A$ so that for $a\in A$ we have $f(a)\in a$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, help me fully understand it. Suppose that $A\equiv\{a_1,a_2\}$. Then, does $\prod_{a\in A}a=\{(a_1,a_1),(a_1,a_2),(a_2,a_1),(a_2,a_2)\}$ or does $\prod_{A}A= \{(a_1,a_1),(a_1,a_2),(a_2,a_1),(a_2,a_2)\} $? Or neither / both?

Comment: $$\prod_A A$$ could be understood as that set, by bijectively identifiying $a_1,a_2$ with $1,2$. $$\prod_{a\in A} A$$ would be $a_1\times a_2$.

Comment: Sorry, the second one should have been $\prod_{a\in A} a$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifying comments. Can I write $\prod_{A}A$ as $\prod_{a\in A}A$ instead? In other words, **is it true that $\prod_{A}A\equiv\prod_{a\in A}A$?**

Comment: Yes, it is. I wrote $\prod_A$ as shorthand for $\prod_{a\in A}$, as we do not depend on $a$. As I said, we can also simply write $A^A$, the space of functions from $A$ to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not able to comment yet, I'll post as an answer. It is $\prod_{A}A$ - and not $\prod_{a\in A}a$ - the set you're pointing out. Cartesian products are defined between sets, not elements of a set. Note that in your example $A$ is in fact finite. When $A$ is uncountable, all the "$A$-indexed vectors", with coordinates in $A$, would be denoted by
$$\prod_{A}A$$

Comment: Note in set theory the elements are also sets. So the second one does also make sense. Also $\prod_A A\neq \emptyset$ is not equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: That $\prod_A A$ is empty if and only if $A$ is empty is *not* equivalent to the Axiom of Choice; it is a theorem of ZF.

Comment: Elaborating on the other comments: consider the function $f(a) = a$. Then $f \in \prod\limits_A A$. No choice needed.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, how can I edit my answer?

Comment: You click on the "Edit" button and make the changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comments. **Can I say that $\prod_{A}A\equiv\prod_{a\in A}A$?**